# Add sources of different library in current jar in maven

Tags: java, maven

We have a java library which works fine and everything. However this is an updated version of a previously used library. Now we don't want to change the group id and artifact id. So we are just copying the files from the other project and creating the library. Meaning 2 different libraries with same classes and everything. Only the group id and artifact id are different. The problem is I want the sources as well. This library does not have any source code and hence the sources jar is empty. How can I create the sources library using the other libraries source code.

We are using maven-shade-plugin plugin in our project.

Comment: "Now we don't want to change the group id and artifact id.", "Only the group id and artifact id are different." how come this possible?

Comment: We have created a different module. Here we have not copied the source code. Used maven-shade-plugin.

Comment: The fact that you use the maven-shade-plugin is key to understanding this question. Please edit this information into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shade plugin has a parameter [createSourcesJar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#createSourcesJar) that when set to true should create a shaded sources jar as well.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much for such a prompt response.